# what's the difference between %d and %lf in C?

Tags: c, printf

in the case of peintf in c what's the difference between %d and %lf

```
printf("Value of n is %d\n", n);
printf("Value of x is %lf\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `*printf`,

`%d` is used to include a value of type `int` as a decimal number.

`%lf` was introduced in C99 as an alias for the existing `%f`.

`%f` is used to include a value of type `double` in decimal notation in the style `[-]ddd.ddd`.

cppreference.com has a great [`printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Example usage:

```c
int         a_signed_int   = ...;
signed char a_signed_char  = ...;
short       a_signed_short = ...;

double      a_double       = ...;
float       a_float        = ...;

printf("%d\n", a_signed_int);
printf("%d\n", a_signed_char);    // `signed char`s are promoted to `signed int`s
printf("%d\n", a_signed_short);   // Same for `signed short int`s

printf("%f\n", a_double);
printf("%f\n", a_float);          // `float`s are promoted to `double`s

printf("%lf\n", a_double );       // Same as above.
printf("%lf\n", a_float);         // Same as above.
```